# FB Graph API - (#3) Application must be whitelisted or users must be testers

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-game-groups

I have FB App and through it created group, so I can invite/add new members of this group (via Facebook Graph API). It works perfect 4 days ago, but now I get error

> "(#3) Application must be whitelisted or users must be testers."

and I can't add new member again. I can't find anywhere what's a "whitelist" and how to add my App on it. Can anyone advise me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application must be in development mode, so you cannot send invitations to the users other than administrators/testers/developers of the application.

So either make your app **live**-

[image]

Or, if you don't want to make the app live for now, add some more **testers** whom you can send the invites-

[image]

**Edit:**

Also check if your app is published in App Center as a game or not? In that case the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/app-game-groups/) says-

> App and Game Groups is currently in **Beta**. While in beta, only games that are in the App Center will have Game Groups enabled. For development purposes, the Game Groups API will work for application admins, developers, testers and test users.

Comment: My App is not in developer mode. I wrote it was ok (I could send invitations) 4 day ago but I get this error now.

Comment: Your app must be in app center to use the groups created by app. PS, pls accept/vote the answer if that clarifies your question. Good lcuk :)

Comment: I see.. but I get error "Your app does not have high enough ratings and user engagement to be reviewed for the App Center at this time." if I try submit App to App Center. I was looking about it and found advices like "you need 1000 users at least", "you need 4000 users at least", "Facebook randomly ask users that uses your app to rate it", etc. .. Is it true? Is it really so complicated?

Comment: Yes it is. Even I cant understand :( My app has 15k+ users but still due to less rating its hows me the same message. So, the no. of users have no effect, it all depends on no. of rating and that depends on facebook :/

Answer (score 0):

Sahil, the App Center requirement should no longer be in place.